Using a Shiny Module Inside Another Shiny Module: Output Not Displaying
I'm working on a Shiny application in R where I need to nest one Shiny module inside another. However, I'm encountering an issue where the output from the nested module does not display (either as a table or a plot).
Could someone help me understand what might be wrong with my approach?
Here’s a simplified version of my code to illustrate the problem:
library(shiny)

# Inner Module UI
nestedModulUI <- function(id, select){
  ns <- NS(id)
  if (select == "Plot") {
    tagList(
      selectInput(ns("x"), "Select X", names(mtcars)),
      selectInput(ns("y"), "Select Y", names(mtcars))
    )
  } else {
    tagList()
  }
}

# Inner Module Server
nestedModulServer  <- function(id, select){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    
    if (select == "Plot") {
      output$thePlot <- renderPlot({
        plot(mtcars[[input$x]], mtcars[[input$y]])
      })
    } else {
      dta <- reactive({
        mtcars
      })
      output$tbl <- renderDataTable(dta(), options = list(pageLength = 10))
    }
    
  })
}

# Outer Module UI
parentModuleUI <- function(id){ 
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(inputId = ns("type"), label = "Which type?", choices = c("Plot", "Table")),
    uiOutput(ns("dynamicsidebar"))
  )
}

# Outer Module Server
parentModuleServer  <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$dynamicsidebar <- renderUI({
      nestedModulUI("nested", input$type)
    })
    
    observe({
      nestedModulServer ("nested", input$type)
    })
    
    
    output$result <- renderUI({
      ns <- session$ns
      if (input$type == "Plot") {
        plotOutput(NS("nested")("thePlot"))
      } else {
        dataTableOutput(NS("nested")("tbl"))
      }
    })
  })
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      parentModuleUI ("test")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("tab1", uiOutput(NS("test") ("result"))),
        tabPanel("tab2")
      )
    )
  )
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output){
  parentModuleServer("test")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



Edited:
when I dont use the nested module the output displays as you can see if the code is modified as follow:
# Outer Module Server
parentModuleServer  <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$dynamicsidebar <- renderUI({
      nestedModulUI("nested", input$type)
    })
    
    # Call the inner module server once, passing the reactive input
    observe({
      nestedModulServer ("nested", input$type)
    })
    
    
    output$result <- renderUI({
      ns <- session$ns
      if (input$type == "Plot") {
        plotOutput(NS("nested")("thePlot"))
      } else {
        dataTableOutput(NS("nested")("tbl"))
      }
    })
    
    dataFile <- reactive({
      mtcars
    })
    output$secondTab <- renderDataTable(dataFile(), options = list(pageLength = 10))
  })
}

# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      parentModuleUI ("test")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("tab1", uiOutput(NS("test") ("result"))),
        tabPanel("tab2", dataTableOutput(NS("test", "secondTab")))
      )
    )
  )
)


Use a browser, inspect, check if some item has a namespace lacking. Use browser() check the input namespaces.

I did so, but could not find any issue

It is odd that you create ns but you use NS

I am new and trying to learn how to use shinymodules. can you please explain more? When I use ns it provides error

In some rare cases you use ns in server, mostly it is implicit. NS I guess never

I changed server to this but still not working :observe({
nestedModuleServer(ns("nested"), input$type)
})           output$result <- renderUI({
if (input$type == "Plot") {
plotOutput(ns("thePlot"))
} else {
dataTableOutput(ns("tbl"))
}
})

I think you should not observe a module. I suggest you refactor to avoid that. Use return in the inner module if necessary.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think your code has a couple of issues especially in the design. Hence, I refactored the code from scratch.
A module should do one thing and just one thing. Yes, with uiOutput we can basically create complete different user interfaces, but this will be a nightmare to debug. Hence, I created 2 dedicated modules table_module_* and plot_module_* which are showing either a plot or a table. The main_module_* module is then responsible for displaying the right module, depending on the selection.
In principle it is a good idea, to regard a module as a closed entity, that is, the module kind of "own" its resources and is the only place where these resources are altered. Yes, we can render a plot inside a module from the outer module, but this is barely a good design. It is better to let the inner module do all the rendering, and the outer module is just there to decide which module to show.
As we need input and output elements which are displayed in different parts of the app, I let the *_ui functions return lists, which contain both sets of elements and both in the main module as well as in the app we use the repsective slots.
Code speaks a thousand words, so here we go:
library(shiny)

plot_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(
    controls = tagList(
      selectInput(ns("x"), "Select X", names(mtcars)),
      selectInput(ns("y"), "Select Y", names(mtcars))
    ),
    output = plotOutput(ns("plt"))
  )
}

plot_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$plt <- renderPlot(
      plot(mtcars[[input$x]], mtcars[[input$y]])
    )
  }) 
}

table_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(
    controls = NULL,
    output = dataTableOutput(ns("tbl"))
  )
}

table_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl <- renderDataTable(mtcars, options = list(pageLength = 10))
  }) 
}

main_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  list(
    controls = tagList(
      selectInput(inputId = ns("type"), label = "Which type?", 
                  choices = c("Plot", "Table")),
      uiOutput(ns("controls"))
    ),
    output = uiOutput(ns("output"))
  )
}

main_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    sub_modules <- list(Plot = plot_module_ui(ns("plt")),
                        Table = table_module_ui(ns("tbl")))
    
    handlers <- list(Plot = plot_module_server("plt"),
                     Table = table_module_server("tbl"))
    
    output$controls <- renderUI({
      sel <- req(input$type)
      sub_modules[[sel]]$controls
    })
    
    output$output <- renderUI({
      sel <- req(input$type)
      sub_modules[[sel]]$output
    })
  })
}

mm <- main_module_ui("main")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      mm$controls
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("tab1", mm$output)
      )
    )
  )
)

# Main Server
server <- function(input, output, session){
  main_module_server("main")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

